# cec controlling other cec enabled device (not TV) - controlling Fire TV from pi

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

I have a pi connected to the TV and can successfully power on, power off, and change sources on tv with:

```
echo "on 0" | cec-client -s
#turn off
echo "standby 0" | cec-client -s
#hdmi 2
echo "tx 4F:82:20:00" | cec-client -s -d 1
#hdmi 3
echo "tx 4F:82:30:00" | cec-client -s -d 1
```

No I'm trying to use CEC to control navigation around menus on FireTV.  I can see it working using my TV remote, but when I try using the PI if fails, e.g

`echo 'tx 12:44:02:00' | cec-client -s` # from 1 (Pi) to 2 (FireTV) 44 for Input and 02 for down

fails (with or without trailing :00).

So the TV remote works to send down to the FireTV, and if I select the Pi as an HDMI input using cec-client I can see the '12:44:02' being used.

Am I missing something simple?  Should the pi and the Fire TV be 'paired' somehow?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i found the problem, the firetv logical address is B, as given by:

`cec-client lad`

And not 2 as i thought it was from

`cec-client scan`

So the following works fine:

`echo "tx 1B:44:02" | cec-client -s -d 1`

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.